# Withdrawing money up to a certain amount over the balance of an account

Tags: c#, visual-studio, button, textbox, display

I am trying to create simple if statements where a program will check the balance of the account and if it is lower than the withdraw amount. If so, the user will be able to withdraw an amount up to the overdraft amount. If the amount is not greater than the overdraft amount, show the remaining overdraft amount in the overdraft textbox. Then display the balance in a textbox. However, the problem I have is that when the user withdraws, the overdraft in the textbox doesn't change. When the customer withdraws more than the balance the amount that they go over should be subtracted from the overdraft amount. The remaining overdraft should be shown in the overdraft textbox.For example, if a person has a balance of 0 and is allowed to overdraft by 50 and tries to overdraft 20 then 30 should still be remaining and displayed in the overdraft textbox and a -20 should be displayed in the balance textbox. (If this makes sense) :D
This is my code up until now

```
 private void withdraw_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Ballance = double.Parse(balance.Text);
        Withdrawtxt = double.Parse(txt_withdraw.Text);
        Overdraftadd = double.Parse(overdraft.Text);

                    //this checks if the user can even make a withdraw. This checks if the withdraw amount is bigger than ballance + Overdraft

        if (Ballance + Overdraftadd >= Withdrawtxt)
        {
            //if the user can withdraw but its more than the ballance then ballance is equal to ballance + the overdraft: If not then the ballance is equal to ballance - withdraw.
            classify = (Ballance < Withdrawtxt) ? Ballance = (Ballance + Overdraftadd) - Withdrawtxt : Ballance = Ballance - Withdrawtxt;
            //this is then displayed in the textbox
            balance.Text = "" + Ballance;
            // here i want to make it so that the overdraft is changed if the user has used some of it. E.G user withdraws but has to use 20 out of 50 overdraft.
            // if ? true false statement
            classify = (Ballance < Withdrawtxt) ? Overdraftadd =  : ;
            //display overdraft in this box.
            overdraft.Text = "" + Overdraftadd;
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand what you are wanting in your overdraft box, but here is some code that will take care of the rest of your needs. In this example, I used overdraft as the amount you want to charge if the account overdrafts. If this is not what you are intending, please clarify.

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            double balance = double.Parse(Balance.Text);
            double withdraw = double.Parse(Withdraw.Text);
            double overdraft = double.Parse(Overdraft.Text);

            if(balance < withdraw)
            {
                balance -= (overdraft + withdraw);
                Balance.Text = balance.ToString();

            }
            else if(balance > withdraw)
            {
                balance -= withdraw;
                Balance.Text = balance.ToString();
            }
        }
```

When the button is pressed the updated balance is shown in the balance text box.

EDIT:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            double balance = double.Parse(Balance.Text);
            double withdraw = double.Parse(Withdraw.Text);
            double overdraft = double.Parse(Overdraft.Text);

            if (balance < withdraw && (balance - withdraw) >= -(overdraft))
            {
                balance -= withdraw;
                overdraft = overdraft + balance;
                Balance.Text = balance.ToString();
                Overdraft.Text = overdraft.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Comment: What I want to do is show the remaining overdraft amount in the overdraft textbox e.g overdraft.Text = remaining overdraft.

Comment: So are saying that a person can only overdraft a certain amount? say go over there balance by the over draft amount? If they do display how much they have remaining?

Comment: Did that help you out any?